# constructing map of if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements, combinations

I have been thinking about a cleaner way to represent combinations of if-statements. For example, the cases described by the code below could potentially be combined in some manner. I could certainly write out all of those combinations, but that would result in sacrificing code-readability for exhaustiveness.

```
if (foo == null) {
            System.out.println("Null input");
            return 1;
        }
        if (foo.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Missing input");
            return 2;
        }
        if (Character.isWhitespace(foo.charAt(0)) || Character.isWhitespace(foo.charAt(foo.length() - 1))){
            System.out.println("var cannot begin or end with spaces");
            return 3;
        }
        String[] words = foo.split(" ");
        if (words.length > 2){
            System.out.println("var cannot be more than two words or intermediate whitespaces");
            return 4;
        }
        if (Pattern.compile("[0-9]").matcher(foo).find()){
            System.out.println("var cannot contain digits");
            return 5;
        }
        if (foo.split("\\t+").length > 1){
            System.out.println("var cannot contain tabs");
            return 6;
        }
        if (this.var.contains(foo)){
            System.out.println("var already exists");
            return 7;
        }
```

I have seen pythonic approaches where each case is condensed into a map. Is there a viable java data structure or approach that would make the code below cleaner while still enabling me to represent all possible combinations of if-statements?

Comment: in this particular case all these conditions can be replaced with single regexp

Comment: Not clear if that approach would yield readable code

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `List` of errors to check for, each with a `Predicate` to evaluate on the input and an error message.

```java
record ErrorCondition(Predicate<String> condition, String message){}
List<ErrorCondition> errors = List.of(new ErrorCondition(s -> s == null, "Null input"), // or Objects::isNull
       new ErrorCondition(String::isEmpty, "Missing input") /* other checks... */);
// ...
int code = 0;
String foo = "";
for (ErrorCondition error: errors) {
    ++code;
    if (error.condition().test(foo)) {
        System.out.println(error.message());
        return code;
    }
}
```

Comment: With this method, you still have to add each combination of ```new Error Condition``` to the list  of errors? If so, it doesn't seem to condense the alternative of just writing a bunch of if statements.

Comment: @J_code Well, there's no way to check conditions if you don't write what the conditions are. With this method, you can cut down on the repetitive structure and only write out the parts that are different. Whether or not this is better is up to you to decide.

Comment: Why isn't `code` a member of `ErrorCondition`?

Comment: @JimGarrison In an actual project, it should probably be put in. All the codes do follow a pattern here though.